# run cron every 105 minutes

Tags: linux, cron

I'm not great with Linux, my apologies if this is easy.

I need to run 7 different scripts via cron at 15 minute intervals. I have worked out that each script needs to run every 105 minutes (every 1 hour & 45 minutes) as follows :

```
Script 1    Script 2    Script 3    Script 4    Script 5    Script 6    Script 7
00:15       00:30       00:45       01:00       01:15       01:30       01:45
02:00       02:15       02:30       02:45       03:00       03:15       03:30
```

etc...

Now I know I can't just put this:

```
*/105 * * * * something
```

Because the minutes will only go up to 59.

Other than writing each one in a line separately, is there an easy way to do this?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` is a good candidate for this problem.

Write a wrapper (or build into your script):

```
#!/bin/bash
at -f $0 now + 105 minutes 
<program>
```

Then use `at -f <script> <time>` for each instance.

---

Or generate the crontab entries using a script (my first draft was a bit too long to be a oneliner):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Ws
use strict;
use DateTime;
our ($period, $offset, $command);
my ($offh, $offm) = split(/:/, $offset || '0:00');
my %crontab = ();
for (my $i = 0; $i < 1440; $i += $period) {
    my ($h,$m) = split /:/, 'DateTime'->today->set('hour', $offh, 'minute', $offm)->add('minutes', $i)->hms;
    $crontab{$m}{$h}++;
}
printf("%02d %-15s * * *\t%s\n", $_, join(',', sort keys %{$crontab{$_}}), $command) for sort keys %crontab;
```

Usage:

```
$ ./gencrontab -period=105 -offset=1:30 -command=myprogram
00 05,12,19        * * *    myprogram
15 00,03,10,17     * * *    myprogram
30 01,08,15,22     * * *    myprogram
45 06,13,20        * * *    myprogram
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `cron` can't do that directly.

What you can do is have a `cron` job that runs every 15 minutes, invoking a wrapper script. The wrapper script can query the current time and decide which of your 7 scripts to execute.

Doing the math is left as an exercise. Don't assume that your wrapper will start *exactly* at the top of the minute; there can be some delay between the time a cron job is scheduled to execute and the time it actually runs, depending on system load.