# Jenkins schedule a job every 105 minutes

Tags: jenkins, schedule

I need to schedule a jenkins job to run every 90 minutes
I tried the following but it did not work
*/45 */1 * * *
But the job ran ever hour and then at every 45 minutes like

- Sep 15, 2016 1:46:09 AM
- Sep 15, 2016 1:01:09 AM
- Sep 15, 2016 12:46:09 AM
- Sep 15, 2016 12:01:09 AM
- Sep 14, 2016 11:46:09 PM
- Sep 14,2016 11:01:09 PM

  and so on

Can any one please suggest me how this is done

Comment: Is it 105 or 90 ? If its 105, use the one I gave below, else change 45 to 30.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to specify two cron jobs for it in the scheduler like this in the same jenkins job - very similar to what one would do for a normal cron in Linux

> ```
> 0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * * /path/to/script
> 45 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * /path/to/script
> ```

Comment: this will execute it in the following order
0,1:45,3:00,4:45 ...
every 105 minutes would be 
0,1:45,3:30,5:15,7:00,8:45

Comment: Hmm. In that case cron won't be a good option. perhaps you could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199949/run-cron-every-105-minutes and in the job just invoke/trigger jenkins job via its rest api which seems a reasonable thing to do.